# Reverse the order of data from an API call works with console.log

Tags: reactjs, console.log, react-chartjs-2

Building a Covid tracker using React and ChartJS-2 I found that I couldn't reverse the incoming data through usual means ie. through the recommendations in the chartJS docs. What seems to work is `console.log(res.data.data.reverse())`
Without this line of code printing to the console, the data displays the opposite way around.
Why is this?

The xAxes params don't take effect, either, but I'm probably just missing a '}' or ']', somewhere.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import axios from 'axios';

const CovidCases = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  const chart = () => {
    //set variables to pass in as dynamic data
    let covCase = [];
    let covDate = [];

    // axios get endpoint
    axios
      .get(
        'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaName=England;areaType=nation&structure={"date":"date","name":"areaName","code":"areaCode","newCasesByPublishDate":"newCasesByPublishDate","cumCasesByPublishDate":"cumCasesByPublishDate","newDeaths28DaysByPublishDate":"newDeaths28DaysByPublishDate","cumDeaths28DaysByPublishDate":"cumDeaths28DaysByPublishDate"}',
      )
   
      .then((res) => {
        // here I reverse the order that the data comes into the console
        console.log(res.data.data.reverse());

     
        for (const dataObj of res.data.data) {
          covCase.push(parseInt(dataObj.newCasesByPublishDate));
          covDate.push(parseInt(dataObj.date));

          // setting the chart data STATE with the chart.js labels and datasets with data: covCase variable
          setChartData({
            // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html for layout requirements
            labels: covDate,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'New Covid Cases by Date (England)',
                data: covCase,
                backgroundColor: ['rgba(81, 250, 157, 0.6)'],
                borderWidth: 2,
              },
            ],
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
      })
    // console.log(covCase, covDate);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="charts" style={{ height: 700, width: 900 }} >
      <Line
        // passing in the STATE as the data to be rendered
        data={chartData}
        // chart.js options parameters
        options={{
          title: { text: 'Covid Cases', display: true },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  autoSkip: true,

                  beginAtZero: true,
                },
              },
            ],
            xAxes: [
              {
                autoSkip: true,
                padding: 10,
                // this section didn't make the difference expected of it. reversing the console.log() did, though!!
                // ticks: {
                //   // reverse: true,
                //   maxTicksLimit: 7,
                //   display: false,
                // },
              },
            ],
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CovidCases;
```

Also, the xAxes parameters were taking no effect but I think I'm within the code recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking why `res.data.data.reverse()` reverses your data? `Array.prototype.reverse` mutates the array in-place. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse Or are you asking about something else? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm actually wondering why, if I omit the console.log(res.data.data.reverse()) the data rendered is in expected order but when this line is not commented out, it reverses the data. ie. The console.log is affecting the outcome of the render. I'm not reversing the data in any other place in the code. –

Comment: `.reverse()` mutates the array in place, so every time you call it reverses the array. Your call inside the `console.log` actively changes the array. If you want to log it, pass it a reference to the array and not a function call.

Comment: Yeah, that's great! Sometimes it just takes a couple of words for something to click. Thanks Drew and Pilchard.

Comment: Ok, seems like you just didn't understand that calling `.reverse` on the array was mutating it. Welcome.